# code line from where zooming is displaying

Tags: php, image, zoom

please visit following link :

media.phtml file = http://pastebin.com/gAwfdtw7

i wanted to know from which line of the code the product images are zooming in the following link :

http://kidsdial.com/chair.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see it's made by Cloud Zoom plugin (http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom) but with an old version - cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js.